# How to configure Checkstyle setup with Oomph

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle, oomph

I'm in the grips of automating our IDE setup with Oomph. I'm currently occupied with Checkstyle. Using the recorder function, no settings get saved when I set our company's own Checkstyle configuration. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/803782/:

Add a `Resource Creation` task to your setup file, since Checkstyle saves its preferences in a dedicated file and not in the Oomph settings.

E. g.:

```
<setupTask
      xsi:type="setup:CompoundTask"
      id="checkstyle.prefs"
      disabled="false"
      name="Checkstyle Setup">
    <setupTask
        xsi:type="setup:ResourceCreationTask"
        excludedTriggers="BOOTSTRAP"
        filter=""
        content="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?>&#xA;&#xA;&lt;checkstyle-configurations file-format-version=&quot;5.0.0&quot; default-check-configuration=&quot;GOOS Checkstyle&quot;>&#xA;  &lt;check-configuration name=&quot;GOOS Checkstyle&quot; location=&quot;configuration\checkstyle\goos-checkstyle.xml&quot; type=&quot;external&quot; description=&quot;&quot;>&#xA;    &lt;additional-data name=&quot;protect-config-file&quot; value=&quot;true&quot;/>&#xA;  &lt;/check-configuration>&#xA;&lt;/checkstyle-configurations>&#xA;"
        targetURL="${workspace.location|uri}/.metadata/.plugins/net.sf.eclipsecs.core/checkstyle-config.xml"
        encoding="UTF-8">
      <description></description>
    </setupTask>
  </setupTask>
```

The `targetURL` specifies the standard saving location for Checkstyle's preferences. This is also the place you can look for your own Checkstyle configuration, so you can add it to the `content` of the Oomph `Resource Creation` task.